# Manipulating a reusable component based on input

Tags: javascript, angular

I have created a reusable component and using it twice inside a component. But I need two buttons, that can manipulate the component individually.

In my case the button for component1 should not update both the instance of the component.

I think I'm doing something wrong by design, but any suggestion will help me.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hfjkmu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Reusable Component:-

```
    import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from '../app.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-reusable',
  templateUrl: './reusable.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reusable.component.css']
})
export class ReusableComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() items:any;
  constructor(
    private service:AppService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.addFruit.subscribe(()=>{
      this.items.unshift({fruit:'Blackberry'});
    });
  }


}
```

Usage:-

```
<button type="button" (click)="Add()">Add Component1</button>
<app-reusable [items]="fruitList1"></app-reusable>
<hr/>
<button type="button" (click)="Add()">Add Component2</button>
<app-reusable [items]="fruitList2"></app-reusable>
```

I want to update only one instance of reusable component at once.
Either instance 1 or 2.

Comment: You're subscribing to the same subject in `app-reusable` component. On each notification the fruit will be added to both `items`. What's your usecase here?

Comment: @31piy on Each subscription I want to add items to a single instance. Let's say I need to add only for first item or second item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to let the service know which component you are calling from.

Try the changes I made in the demo.

**app.component.html**

```
<button type="button" (click)="Add(1)">Add Component1</button>

<app-reusable [items]="fruitList1" [componentNumber]="1"></app-reusable>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
Add(componentNumber:number){
   this.service.addFruit.next(componentNumber);
}
```

**reusable.component.ts:**

`@Input() componentNumber: number;`

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.service.addFruit.subscribe((x) => {
      if (x == this.componentNumber)
        this.items.unshift({ fruit: 'Blackberry' });
    });
  }
```

**[Working Stackbiltz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9bqfuz?embed=1&file=src/app/reusable/reusable.component.ts)**

Comment: You are welcome.. Please accept the answer if this helped.

Comment: To upgrade this answer, I would use the "filter" pipe instead of an if: `this.service.addFruit.pipe(filter(x => x === this.componentNumber)).subscribe(...)`

Answer (score 1):

More cleaner approch would be simply pass the component instance and call related method so create a method in your reusable component something like

```
addFruit(){
    this.items.unshift({fruit:'Blackberry'});
  }
```

Modify your add method to get component as instance and call this method

```
 Add(instance:ReusableComponent){
    instance.addFruit();
  }
```

Then add hash to seprate each instance and pass instance in method

```
 <button type="button" (click)="Add(instance1)">Add Component1</button>
<app-reusable [items]="fruitList1" #instance1></app-reusable>
```

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fnhrqx)

Comment: Cool! But we wanted to handle the manipulation inside reusable component.

Answer (score 1):

Each instance of ReusableComponent is subscribed to the Subject addFruit. Clicking on the button will update Subject value which will trigger all subscriptions.

In order to avoid this, you will need to add a filter in a subscription which ignores values from other components by adding some when doing `this.service.addFruit.next();`. You can do filtering with RXJS filter operator. https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/filter

Another idea is to create a subscription for each component in service and save them in some map/object in service. When a component requests a subscription from service it would add an entry to map which would be subjectId: new Subject(). You would return that new subject for the component to subscribe. Instead of doing next() directly you would call service method addNewFruit(subjectId: string, newFruit: string): void.
Map would be:

```
{
     'firstId': Subject,
     'secondId': Subject,
}
```

The most simple idea for this case is to use ViewChild and call method addFruit from the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having subscription of APP service in the reusable component , on click of button you should modified the input provided to your components. If you update the fruitList1 or fruitList2 at a time then it would not update the another instance of the component.